# Laplace Transforms and Inverse Laplace

Tags: calculus, laplace-transform

Please can you check my answers for the below Laplace questions.

thank you.

**Question 1**

Find the Laplace transform forms of the following piecewise function:

$$g(t)=\left\{ \begin{align}
  & (4+t)^2\quad,t>-4 \\ 
 & 0\qquad\quad\quad,t< -4 \\ 
\end{align} \right.$$

**MY Answer:**

$$\mathcal{L}(t^2)=\frac{2}{s^3} $$

$$\mathcal{L}{(t^2g(t))}=\frac{2e^{4s}}{s^3}$$

**Question 2**

Find the inverse Laplace of : $\large\frac{e^{-5s}}{s-2}$

**MY Answer:**

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left( \frac{e^{-5s}}{s-2}\right)  = e^{2(t-5)}$$

Or
$$ u(t-5). e^{2(t-5)}$$

Comment: Format your maths text using Latex. See [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) for help.

Comment: Thank you Mattos I will take note of this in the future

Comment: @Moo thank you. For the first question do I have to simplify the expression $$(4+t)^{2}$$ and then apply the Laplace to it?

Comment: @Moo thank you, there should be three Laplace Transform terms. When i expand the expression I get $$(16+8t+t^{2})$$ then the laplace Trans will be $$(16/s)$$ + $$(8/s^{2})$$ + $$(2/s^{3})$$ will this be the correct answer? Nope I not too sure of the unit step function. What confuses me is the piecewise functions is where they specify that t>-4

Comment: So my answer will be $$((16.e^{4s})/s) + ((8.e^{4s})/(s^{2})+ ((2.e^{4s})/(s^{3}))$$ is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Question 1** Observing that $$\mathcal L \{t^2u(t)\}=\frac{2}{s^3}$$ where $u(t)$ is the Heaviside's function, and using the shifting property we have 
$$\mathcal L \{g(t)\}=\mathcal L \{(t+4)^2u(t+4)\}=\frac{2}{s^3}\mathrm e^{4s}$$

**Question 2** Observing that $$\mathcal L \{\mathrm e^{-at}f(t)\}=F(s+a)$$ and that $$\mathcal L \{h(t-b)u(t-b)\}=\mathrm e^{-bs}H(s)$$
we have for $f(t)=u(t)$
$$
\frac{1}{s-2}=\mathcal L \{\mathrm e^{2t}u(t)\}
$$
and for $h(t)=\mathrm e^{2t}u(t)$
$$
\frac{1}{s-2}\mathrm e^{-5s}=\mathcal L \{h(t-5)u(t-5)\}=\mathcal L \{\mathrm e^{2(t-5)}u(t-5)\}
$$